# How to restore ntfs partition table in freebsd

Tags: freebsd, data-recovery, truenas

I accidentally deleted my partition table on my old disk through:

```
gpart delete -i ada3
gpart destory ada3
```

Which contains all files on it. How can restore these data on this disk?
I tried testdisk, but the drive is not showing up in the list. However, it is showing in:

```
camcontrol devlist
```

Should I recreate gpt on it (it is originally MBR)?

```
 gpart create -s gpt ada1
```

Comment: testdisk under windows seem works. Not sure why freebsd version cannot